# How to vertically center a dynamic height fixed element?

Tags: css, overlay, css-position, fixed

I'm making an overlay window thing and I'm trying to vertically center the message in the center of the screen.... this is my CSS thus far:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 276px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6d748b;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #b9c1d6;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;      
    z-index: 7500;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `top: 50%;`? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tp8TB/1/)

Comment: @Rofez I thought you had to apply negative margins of half the height of the element when doing that method?

Comment: Yep my bad, but you can check my new answer =).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one way (assuming you're only trying to center one element):

```
#overlay {
    top: 50%;
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -o-transform: tranlslateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4LkQ/1/)

Comment: I just tried it in IE8, which I need it to work in, and it worked great! Btw..... what do you mean it only supports a single element? The element can't have child elements?